# How to handle redundant types in Crystal?

Tags: crystal-lang

I'm using the [crystal language](https://crystal-lang.org/), and it's been great so far. Unfortunately, I feel like ***my*** code is becoming a bit too messy with types everywhere.

For example:

```
  # ---------=====----++---
  # Grab characters
  # ---------=====----++---
  def handle_character_list(msg, client)
    result = {} of String => Array(Tuple(Int64, String, String, Int16, Int8)) | Int32 | Int16 | Int64 | String

    result["characters"] = db.query_all "select character_id, character_name, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%b:%d:%Y:%l:%i:%p') AS created, level, cc from rpg_characters where user_id = ? ", client.user_id,
      as: {Int64, String, String, Int16, Int8}

    result["max_char_slots"] = client.user_data["max_char_slots"]

    puts result
  end
```

While looking at the [db.query_all method](http://crystal-lang.github.io/crystal-db/api/0.5.0/DB/QueryMethods.html#query_all%28query%2C%2Aargs%2Castype%3AClass%29-instance-method), it says:

> returns an array where the value of each row is read as the given type

With the aforementioned above, why do I need to explicitly set those types again to my `result` variable, if they are going to be returned?

I feel like I'm doing something wrong, and any advice/insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The first thing that jumps out at me is the size of the type of your hash. You seem to be using `Hash` the same way as in Ruby. Don't.

In Ruby, or other dynamic languages, `Hash`es or objects are used as generic data containers, almost like unnamed classes. In Crystal, hashes have a single type for the key, and a single type for the value, which makes them unsuited for the task. You want to tell Crystal more about the structure of your data, so you don't have to keep repeating that.

The first thing to do is look at the `result` object. It can simply be transformed into a `record Result`:

```
record Result,
  characters: Array({Int64, String, String, Int16, Int8}),
  max_char_slots: Int32
```

the method then becomes

```
def handle_character_list(msg, client)
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT character_id, character_name, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%b:%d:%Y:%l:%i:%p') AS created, level, cc
    FROM rpg_characters
    WHERE user_id = ?
    SQL
  characters = db.query_all sql, client.user_id, as: {Int64, String, String, Int16, Int8}

  max_char_slots = client.user_data["max_char_slots"]

  Result.new(characters, max_char_slots)
end
```

However, by looking at the method it might be that this `Result` record is only used in one place - to return data from this method. In that case it's unlikely you want to give it a more formal name. In this case you could use a `NamedTuple`. They're a bit like an anonymous record.

```
def handle_character_list(msg, client)
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT character_id, character_name, DATE_FORMAT(created, '%b:%d:%Y:%l:%i:%p') AS created, level, cc
    FROM rpg_characters
    WHERE user_id = ?
    SQL

  {
    characters: db.query_all(sql, client.user_id, as: {Int64, String, String, Int16, Int8}),
    max_char_slots: client.user_data["max_char_slots"]
  }
end
```

Going further, we can see that a "Character" is also a type:

```
class Character
  getter id : Int64
  getter name : String
  getter created : Time
  getter level : Int16
  getter cc : Int8

  def initialize(@id, @name, @created, @level, @cc)
  end
end
```

We can then use the `DB.mapping` to define how the `Character` class looks in the database.

```
class Character
  DB.mapping({
    id: Int64,
    name: String.
    created: Time,
    level: Int16,
    cc: Int8
  })

  def initialize(@id, @name, @created, @level, @cc)
  end
end
```

This definition is equivalent to the previous one because `DB.mapping` automatically generates getters for us.

```
def handle_character_list(msg, client)
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT character_id, character_name, created, level, cc
    FROM rpg_characters
    WHERE user_id = ?
    SQL

  {
    characters: db.query_all(sql, client.user_id, as: Character),
    max_char_slots: client.user_data["max_char_slots"]
  }
end
```

Going even further, I'd extract that into two methods, each one doing just one thing, and I'd probably make `client.user_data` more type safe:

```
def characters_for_user(user_id)
  sql = <<-SQL
    SELECT character_id, character_name, created, level, cc
    FROM rpg_characters
    WHERE user_id = ?
    SQL
  db.query_all(sql, user_id, as: Character)
end

def handle_character_list(msg, client)
  {
    characters: characters_for_user(client.user_id),
    max_character_slots: client.user_data.max_char_slots
  }
end
```

This is just my thought process on how I'd write the code you've shown. I've made a lot of assumptions about your code and database which might be wrong (i.e. "created" is a DATETIME in mysql). I'm attempting to show a thought process, not a finished solution. Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow,  utilizing `DB.mapping` in a `Character` class is exactly what makes this less redundant, and far more simpler than what I was doing. This answer goes above and beyond and it's truly appreciated. In fact, I bookmarked it